# ¿Cómo quitar Warning de mi código?

Tags: c, linux

Me gustaría saber como puedo quitar los siguientes Warning de mi código:

```
warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast 
    return byte;

 warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘int *’
    printf("%s %s %s %d %s %s\n", permisos,user, grupo, tamanio, tiempo, nom);
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
int *getSize (size_t s){
    int byte;
    byte = s;
    return byte;    
}
void do_Info(char *nom){
    struct stat s;
    char *user, *grupo, *permisos, *tiempo;
    int *tamanio;
    if (lstat(nom,&s)==-1){
        printf("Imposible acceder a %s:%s\n",nom,strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    user = getUser(s.st_uid);
    grupo = getGroup(s.st_gid);
    permisos=getPermisos(s.st_mode);
    tiempo = getTime(s.st_mtime);
    tamanio = getSize(s.st_size);

    printf("%s %s %s %d %s %s\n", permisos,user, grupo, tamanio, tiempo, nom);  
}
```

Un saludo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Que tal si en lugar de `tamanio` pones `*tamanio`? Lo que tienes es un `int *` no un `int`, la diferencia es un puntero.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero para byte, me sigue saliendo el mismo warning

Comment: Quitale el asterisco en la definición...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veamos tu código:

```
int *getSize (size_t s){
  int byte;
  byte = s;
  return byte;    
}
```

Esa función devuelve un **puntero a `int`**. Sin engargo, lo que estás haciendo es devolver un `int`. Ese es tu primer *warning*, e, indirectamente, el motivo del segundo.

Una *ligera* molestia del tipo `off_t` ( `struct stat.st_size` ) es que ... no hay un *indicador de tipo* para el en la función `printf( )`. Dicho tipo es *dependiente de la implementación*.

Segun la norma [*POSIX* v2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html):

> blkcnt_t and off_t are  extended signed integral types

es decir, un entero con signo. Actualmente, la mayoría de los sistemas lo definen como un entero con signo de 64 bits; un `int64_t`.

Una forma bastante *portable* de mostrarlo es mediante la cabecera `<inttypes.h>` y la macro `PRId64` alli definida. De esta forma, te ahorras tu función `getSize( )`, y se eliminan todos los avisos:

```
void doInfo( char *nom ) {
  ...
  user = getUser(s.st_uid);
  grupo = getGroup(s.st_gid);
  permisos=getPermisos(s.st_mode);
  tiempo = getTime(s.st_mtime);

  printf("%s %s %s %" PRId64 " %s %s\n", permisos, user, grupo, s.st_size, tiempo, nom );  
}
```

Observa que la *macro* se indica **fuera de la cadena**, separándola mediante espacios. Esto es debido a como C maneja las cadenas.

Esa *conversión* **debería** de ser portable. Si tu sistema usa un `off_t` mas pequeño, será automaticamente convertido a `int64_t`, por lo que no deberías de tener ningún problema.